# HP ML150 G6 and P410 - Adding a second drive cage

Tags: hp

Have a ML150 G6 and a P410 RAID controller installed in a Win 2008 R2 server. The P410 has a single cage with 4x 146GB 10K SAS drives. I want to add a second cage for 4x SATA drives that are currently on the B110I Software controller on a non-hot plug cage.

In reading the requirements from the ML150 G6 spec sheet (http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13249_na/13249_na.pdf), here is what is required.;

NOTE: Support for more than 4 hard drives requires the purchase of one (1) Hot-plug hard drive cage (P/N:
487737-B21), one (1) HP 750W Common Slot Gold Hot Plug Power Supply Kit (P/N: 512327-B21), one (1)
Redundant Power Supply Enablement Kit (P/N: 508544-B21) and HP Smart Array P410 Controller (if not
already part of the configuration).

The spec sheet mentions the mini-SAS cable later in the document.

I am curious why the secondary power supply & kit is required? I see that people generally buy another P410(i) instead of adding support for a 2nd cage. Is that the recommendation? Is a SAS expander needed? I am seeking more clarification on HP's elusive upgrade path on hardware.

I have no more PCI-E slots available unless I upgrade the two NC360T's to a single NC364T which is why I prefer no additional cards.

Answer (score 2):

A P-Series HBA with an "i" at the end means it's integrated into the motherboard (which is not exactly what you'd imagine in some models, long story anyway). The P410/P410i has 2 mini-SAS connectors (4 drives each, or 4 lanes for connections to expanders each).

Hot-swap or not is a function of the card and the drives, not much to do with the cage (though marketing may say otherwise).

The standard 460W Power Supply is going to be strained to power 8 drive and a whole server. So the 750W upgrade is recommended/required (depending on how you read it). The 460W stock unit may not have connections necessary for the extra drive cage either.

Comment: I found another post that confirms there will likely be a power issue due to resources in use on the machine. 

http://forum.wegotserved.com/index.php?/topic/13192-hp-ml150-g6/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add personal experience to this post...

You can add the appropriate cage, in my case the non-hot swap cage to get another 4 drives. I added a SAS controller to run 8 drives. With the appropriate cables, everything connects properly.

However...the system will not power on with all 6 hard drives plugged in (2TB 10k SAS). I can get the system to run if I unplug 1 drive, allow the unit to power on, then plug in the last hard drive. Not exactly a good production setup, but if you're willing to work around it for a home server.

Otherwise, you'll need a beefier power supply. Guessing, but it looks like the mounting and connectors are a standard ATX power supply. You might be able to (I haven't tried this yet) install an off-the-shelf >600W supply and be good.